# Username and Password login

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, ttk

I'd like to create a Login in which will open a text/csv file read the "Valid" usernames and passwords from the file and then if whatever the user has added has matched what was in the file then it will allow access to the rest of the program

**How would i integrate the code below into one of which opens a file reads valid usernames and passwords and checks it against the users input**

Currently i have something which works but there is only one password which i have set in the code.

```
 Password = StringVar()
 Username = StringVar()

 def EnterPassword():
        file = open('Logins.txt', 'w') #Text file i am using
        with open('Logins.txt') as file:    
             data = file.read() #data=current text in text file


        UsernameAttempt = Username.get()#how to get value from entry box
        PasswordAttempt = Password.get()#how to get value from entry box

        if PasswordAttempt == '' and UsernameAttempt == '':
            self.delete()
            Landlord = LandlordMenu()
        else:
            PasswordError = messagebox.showerror('Password/Username         Entry','Incorrect Username or Password entered.\n         Please try again.')
PasswordButton = Button(self.GenericGui,text = 'Landlord Section',height = 3, width = 15, command = EnterPassword, font = ('TkDefaultFont',14),relief=RAISED).place(x=60,y=175)
```

Some assistance would be appreciated

Comment: what sort of assistance do you need? Your question doesn't include an actual question.

Comment: @BryanOakley Id like to integrate the code i have currently so it checks the users username and password input against a "valid logins" file. All possible logins will be stored in the text/csv file instead of only having a username and password set in the code, which i currently have

Comment: There isn't any attempt to read from file or anything similar to it in your given code. What you should do is: Read from file, assign id and pass.es to respective lists and check if entered ones are in those lists. First try to implement this and then ask question about the step you stuck or get error etc.

Comment: @Lafexlos I added a little more about file opening from what i know but not sure where to go from here on

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at some documentation. Your question in "Coding Comments" -> `#how to get value from entry box` is easy to be solved using [official documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm#M43).

For reading files there is also [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) on strings and file operations (reading file line by line into string, using `string.split(';')` to get arrays instead of row-strings).

Please do read documentation before writing applications. You do not need to know the complete API of all python modules but where to look. It is very exhausting to be dependent on other users / developers when there is no actual need for it (as there is very detailed documentation and tons of howtows for that kind of stuff).

This is not meant to be offensive but to show you how easy you can get documentation. Both results where first-results from a search engine. (ddg)

Please keep in mind that SO is neither a code writing service nor a let-me-google-that-for-you forum.